# Killing sub process that run inside a thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I'm using python 3.5.3 with PyQT 5 and I have written GUI with it.
This GUI run python code python code with subprocess.run.

In order to leave my GUI active and not frozen during the subprocess operation , i'm running the subprocess in a thread.

In the GUI i have stop button that if the user pressed  , I want to terminate the subprocess.

I have no problem to kill the thread by using terminate method of the thread.
But that's don't terminate the subprocess.

I've tried to use Popen instead of run but I cant make it to run as subprocess.run does.
in addition , I prefer to use the recommended way by Python that's give me also the check_error option

This is how I use subprocess:

```
class c_run_test_thread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self,test_file,log_file):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.test_file = test_file
        self.log_file = log_file

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        # Thread logic

        try:
            # Run the test with all prints and exceptions go to global log file
            self.test_sub_process = subprocess.run(["python", self.test_file],stdout = self.log_file, stderr = self.log_file,check = True)

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
        print("Error : {}".format(error))

    # Flush memory to file
    self.log_file.flush(

def stop(self):

    # Flush memory to file
    self.log_file.flush()
```

And I terminate the thread by

```
# Stop test thread
self.thread_run_test.terminate()
```

To sum things up , I want to kill thread while killing its sub process too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other simpler ways to this, but what I did was to

1. Use `subprocess.Popen` to run a sub process, instead of `subprocess.run`, since the latter will not return before the process is terminated
2. Check if the process is terminated using `Popen.poll`
3. Kill the process using `Popen.kill`

A sample code would be sth. like the following:

```
self.test_sub_process = subprocess.Popen(["python", self.test_file],
                                         stdout=self.log_file,
                                         stderr=self.log_file)
```

Wait for termination:

```
print("Return code: {}".format(self.test_sub_process.wait()))
```

Or if you want to do something while waiting:

```
while self.test_sub_process.poll() is None:
    doSomething()
print("Return code: {}".format(self.test_sub_process.poll()))
```

Then in `thread_run_test.terminate()`, you can kill the process

```
self.test_sub_process.kill()
```

HTH.

Comment: you didn't change the .run to Popen .
does it have the same parameters? the PIPE in .run method its nicer than os.read , can I use Popen and PIPE as today and still use Popen?

Comment: @Gil.I Have changed it to use `Popen`.

Comment: when I used your suggestion , some of the stdout is not written to the log file. I dont know why.  Instead I used the following :
self.test_sub_process = subprocess.Popen(["python", self.test_file], stdout = self.log_file, stderr = self.log_file)

        while (self.test_sub_process.poll() is None):
            print ("Test is running")
        
        print("Return code: {}".format(self.test_sub_process.poll())) 
The return code pare is of course outside of the loop
and now the log is full without missing any data

Comment: @Gil.I, it is interesting that it may lose some `stdout` messages. Does `self.test_file` write to both `stderr` and `stdout`? I believe they should be handled differently. Anyway, it looks like it is more convenient for you to just use file objects instead of `PIPE`s. I've updated the response to meet your situation better.

Comment: I posted a followup question ,to know how  to kill the subprocess in orderly fashion , while calling all objects destrcutors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422527/how-to-kill-sub-process-in-anytime-while-closing-it-in-orderly-fashion